# ASP.NET Controller with DataRow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm building a simple ASP.NET application that communicates with a SQL server database. In a separate project, I have the dataset that was generated by Visual Studio. I'm trying to expose an API that will display all users in the database, but I'm getting an exception.

Here is the code:

```
public class UserController : ApiController {

    public IEnumerable<GWDataSet.usersRow> GetAllUsers() {
        GWDataSet gw = new GWDataSet();
        usersTableAdapter adapter = new usersTableAdapter();
        adapter.Fill(gw.users);

        return gw.users.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

And this is the exception:

```
Type 'System.Data.DataRow' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.
```

Is there a way around this, other than to manually edit the system-generated code? My fear is that next time I make a change to the dataset, it will overwrite all the datacontract elements I add in. I would think there's a way to do this, but I can't seem to find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you cannot share DataRow objects. They are not serializable. If you want to share it, you should create DTO objects. It is a good pratice of shareing objects from services, APIs, etc. Tru to convert your DataRow to a DTO object. Try something like:

Create your class to be this DTO, for sample:

```
[Serializable]
public class UserDTO
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Birthday { get; set; }
    /* other properties you need */
}
```

And in your web api, try this:

```
public class UserController : ApiController {

    public IEnumerable<UserDTO> GetAllUsers() {
        GWDataSet gw = new GWDataSet();
        usersTableAdapter adapter = new usersTableAdapter();
        adapter.Fill(gw.users);

        List<UserDTO> list = new List<UserDTO>();

        foreach(DataRow row in gw.users.Rows) 
        {
            UserDTO user = new UserDTO();
            user.FirstName = row["Name"].ToString();
            // fill properties

           list.Add(user);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had started doing that, but I'm afraid that when I apply this to the database I want to (I'm learning about this now), I'll have to maintain code in two areas, that are basically the same thing. The DataRow exposes the user information from the database, so I was hoping that I could reuse that in a simple way.

Comment: @DanChampagne Filipe is right, you'll want to create a separate class to represent the data in your API.  Even though it might feel like you're duplicating work, you really aren't.  You probably won't want to expose absolutely everything in your database through the API - you'll want to think about its design separate from the DB.  Also, manually editing auto-generated code always ends in blood. :)

Answer (score 0):

Going off of Felipe's answer (and after remembering that I need to deal with the dreaded DBNull), here is the final method I built:

```
    public IEnumerable<GW.Entities.user> GetAllUsers() {
        try {
            GWDataSet gw = new GWDataSet();
            List<GW.Entities.user> users = new List<user>();
            usersTableAdapter adapter = new usersTableAdapter();

            adapter.Fill(gw.users);

            foreach (GWDataSet.usersRow row in gw.users.Rows) {
                users.Add(new GW.Entities.user {
                    UserId = row.IsNull("UserId") ? 0 : row.UserId,
                    UserName = row.IsNull("UserName") ? "" : row.UserName,
                    EmailAddress = row.IsNull("EmailAddress") ? "" : row.EmailAddress,
                    UserPasswordLastChange = row.IsNull("UserPasswordLastChange") ? DateTime.MinValue : row.UserPasswordLastChange,
                    LastLogin = row.IsNull("LastLogin") ? DateTime.MinValue : row.LastLogin,
                    StatusCd = row.IsNull("StatusCd") ? "" : row.StatusCd,
                    LastTimestamp = row.IsNull("LastTimestamp") ? null : row.LastTimestamp
                });
            }

            return users;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Which gives me an output of:

```
<ArrayOfuser xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/GW.Entities">
    <user>
        <EmailAddress>seraieis@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
        <LastLogin>2012-12-19T20:48:26.41</LastLogin>
        <LastTimestamp>AAAAAAAARlI=</LastTimestamp>
        <StatusCd>A</StatusCd>
        <UserId>1</UserId>
        <UserName>seraieis</UserName>
        <UserPasswordLastChange>0001-01-01T00:00:00</UserPasswordLastChange>
    </user>
</ArrayOfuser>
```